# What should be the HTTP Error code for duplicate request where existing request is still in progress

Tags: rest, http-response-codes

What is the correct Http response code for a POST create request, where the existing create request is still in progress while the client has raised a similar request again?

Will [409](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409) be the correct error code? Or should we use [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)?

The whole assumption on why a client might retry the request is either because of a coding bug or because of a timeout or network issue on its end. And we expect the Clients should be able to retry the same request without changing anything.

Comment: It depends on if for a successful submission if you need to return anything more than a 200 series code.  If it is usually only a 200 OK or 201 Created, but you are still processing and will eventually will create it, then I would return a 202 Accepted, as there is no need for them to retry.  What do you intend to return if the first one succeeded and they do another create request?  See this blog https://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/ which recommends 429

Comment: The previous request can still fail probably with a 500 as the request latency is more than 10 sec. For successful request the consecutive requests will be 200.

Thanks for the reference.